# Alias to dependent type only allows class types on GCC 12, but allows fundamental types on most other compilers

Tags: c++, dependent-type, type-alias, template-aliases, gcc12

I found that the code snippet below compiles fine on gcc 11, clang, and MSVC, but starting with gcc 12.1, it gives the error:

```cpp
using Y = typename Derived::template X<1>;  // offending line
```

`error: 'class Derived<T>::X<1>' resolves to 'Base<double>::X<1>' {aka 'double'}, which is not a class type`

Why does the alias need to resolve to a class type for this to be a properly formed alias?

Minimal Example Code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TY8YMn3Ee)):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Base {
  template <int I>
  using X = T;
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : public Base<T> {
  using Y = typename Derived::template X<1>;
};

struct O {};

int main() {
  std::cout << typeid(Derived<double>::Y).name() << std::endl;  // error
  std::cout << typeid(Derived<O>::Y).name() << std::endl;       // works
}
```

In the code in question, I'm trying to create an alias to a parent's (templated) alias, but it only works when the alias resolves to a class type.  Of course, something like `using Y = double;` is perfectly legal, and when any of `Base`, `Derived`, or `X` are *not* templated it also seems to work fine, so how come this particular combination of dependent types makes it so that `X<something>` is no longer allowed to resolve to e.g. arithmetic types, and only on gcc 12.1 and up?

I skimmed through the [gcc 12 change list](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-12/changes.html) but didn't see anything that struck out to me as related.

(I'm using c++11 but it that doesn't seem to be relevant as it also occurs when specifying c++14, 17, 0x)

Comment: `using Y = typename Base<T>::template X<1>;` passes for all compilers [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4j91799n).

Comment: This is plainly a compiler regression.